# How to get remainder of 2 double using % operator?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get remainder of 2 double using % operator

```
double x = 965.606698735538;
double y = 482.803349367769;
var mod = x % y;
```

Expected value is 0

Actual value is 482.803349367769

Can someone help why its behaving so strange.

Comment: @scartag in the OP's case, `2x == y` so the answer should be zero.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(x % y)` returns 0 in my fiddle. What's going wrong actually?

Comment: Most likely you're a victim of floating point limited accuracy/precision: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Like @TetsuyaYamamoto says: This actually works, so the error must be elsewhere. It'll be a rounding error.

Comment: Are you outputting `y` rather than `mod`?

Comment: I intentionally added one decimal place on the second operand & suddenly it turns into `482.xxxx`. The `double` data type precision error exactly confirmed the issue.

Comment: Though the duplicate question deals with + the answer answers perfectly why this happens, floating point is not accurate so the division isn't perfectly divisable by 2.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quirk of binary floating point arithmetic.

The closest (IEEE754) `double` to 482.803349367769 is 482.80334936776898757671006023883819580078125

The closest `double` to 965.606698735538 is
965.6066987355379751534201204776763916015625

As you can see the latter is not exactly twice the former; in fact it is just under twice that. Which accounts for the large remainder that you see.

You need to be careful when using `%` with floating point arguments.

Comment: This is true, but if you actually run the OP's code, it returns 0.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That is the *formatter* being clever with the output.

Comment: It's not the formatter - there's no way a formatter would change ~482 to 0...

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Touche.

Comment: But it definitely is being caused by a rounding error, like you say - it's just that the OP's code does not actually exhibit the problem (at least, not on my PC).

Comment: I assume it is the formatting of the numbers that the OP is reading out of the debugger. The ones in the question are almost certainly calculated in his original code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: It's possible their processor is using 80 bit floating point internally.

Comment: @Bathsheba Do you have any alternate solution

Comment: C# has a built-in decimal type which could be a good alternative. Personally I'd arrange the calculations so the remainder operator takes integral type arguments.

Comment: I use the aproach of calculating the rest missing to the next or previous "full number" and having a tolerance value. See this: https://gist.github.com/GW-FUB/1a5d3f3abb88aba90aec6de0ea461d53